# transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug error at build

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

My React Native app was working yesterday.

I was working on a new version and wanted to push it to the Google Play Store. 
I tried fixing the library version for facebook and for react-native-fetch-blob.

I have been having this error for 6 hours now at build.

```
/Users/nicoara/Documents/GitHub/Parkour/node_modules/react-native-firebase/android/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar: D8: Interface `com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener` not found. It's needed to make sure desugaring of `io.invertase.firebase.admob.RNFirebaseAdMobRewardedVideo` is correct. Desugaring will assume that this interface has no default method.

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/robolectric-utils/3.1.4/803d061ec7bd2ad78bcb74fb10caaeeb2dc4a74a/robolectric-utils-3.1.4.jar
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
        at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:420)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/robolectric-utils/3.1.4/803d061ec7bd2ad78bcb74fb10caaeeb2dc4a74a/robolectric-utils-3.1.4.jar
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:909)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:834)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:904)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:70)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
        ... 10 more


> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.robolectric/robolectric-utils/3.1.4/803d061ec7bd2ad78bcb74fb10caaeeb2dc4a74a/robolectric-utils-3.1.4.jar
```

Here is my environment:

```
Nicoaras-MBP:Parkour nicoara$ react-native info
info 
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
      Memory: 41.30 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 8.10.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.5.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 5.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 11.4, macOS 10.13, tvOS 11.4, watchOS 4.3
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
        Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.1, 25.0.3, 26.0.2, 27.0.3, 28.0.3, 29.0.2
        System Images: android-25 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
      Xcode: 9.4.1/9F2000 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.5 => 16.8.5 
      react-native: 0.59.0 => 0.59.0 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-create-library: 3.1.2
```

it might be because "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0", so I attach the gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    api 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+' // support react-native-v0.22-rc+
    api 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
```

my package-json:

```
{
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "resources/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "name": "parkour",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "devtools": "react-devtools"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "MyThumbnailLibrary": "file:./MyThumbnailLibrary",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.10.0",
    "react": "16.8.5",
    "react-native": "0.59.0",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-autolink": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.5.0",
    "react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.3.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.12",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.440",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^4.4.0",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.1.6",
    "react-native-ux-cam": "^5.1.11",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-video": "4.4.2",
    "react-native-video-processing": "^1.20.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: i was having a similar problem today.  I "fixed" it by restarting my machine, building the APK first, then building the bundle.  YMMV.

Comment: Hello. I have doubt the issue has something to do with fbsdk, unless you are able to revert to previous version of the fbsdk and compile and run successfully. Im judging based on the log you shared `D8: Interface `com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener` not found.`.  

What I normally do when I face build issue like this, I'll always revert my build to the success state and upgrade the lib one by one to make sure which is the problem maker. Could you also share you app/build.gradle? Need more info to help you.

Comment: Is `react-native-fbsdk` newly added? It worked before adding this library and stopped working after?

Answer (score 0):

You get this type of error when multiple libraries from you dependency tree require another library or some required library for one of your dependencies is missing. In your case robolectric-utils-3.1.4.jar is either imported twice or not imported at all.